# Live-stream HD camera to stream on one's own Wordpress website

Tags: camera, webvideos, live-recording

I was wondering if someone could help me with this project with live-stream cameras. I am not sure what the best camera / broadcast transmitter or internet package I should purchase to ensure that it goes smoothly. The project will take place in Italy. Thank you so much for your time in advance!!!

The IDEA: 4 live-streaming HD web cameras that are mounted to a headpiece at a petting zoo. The cameras have wifi transmitters that stream footage to a wordpress-based website where all four cameras are showing their live video feed (using the VideoWhisper plugin). The visitors will wear the devices so it is their POV so via the web, it is as if one is virtually petting the animals. Online viewers can choose which camera of the 4 they would like to see in full HD or switch to view another to see/virtually pet other animals at the zoo.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question depends largely on your budget. A pretty easy and standard config (but which is not really cheap) would be using GoPros with the corresponding helmet / head mount and plugging it into something like a Teradek VidiU http://teradek.com/pages/vidiu - configuring it for your favourite streaming provider and pointing your WordPress plug-in to show that stream.

A wired article about the vidiu and two other streaming devices:
http://www.wired.com/2014/10/hd-streamer-boxes/

Depending on how long this needs to run, you should maybe add an additional battery solution to the setup, the vidius internal battery only seems to run for 60 minutes...

Apparently GoPro themself announced a streaming transmitter / receiver System called heroCast but it seems to be even more expensive than the teradek.

Alternatively you could use a smartphone to do the recording / transmitting with something like the bambuser app / service, most certainly the quality will be worse than the GoPro / vidiu solution, but cheaper. For both solutions you additionally need to make sure you got a decent WiFi coverage for the areas you want to be part of your project or - broadcast the stuff over LTE / UMTS, involving extra cost for the appropriate data plan you need to get in that case.